# Curried functions with futures in scala

Tags: scala, function-composition

I am learning scala and would like to understand how `Futures` could be implemented for a curried functions

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object MainApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val x = curriedMultiply(10) _ andThen Await.result(curriedAdd(10),Duration.Inf)

    println(x(2))



  }

  def curriedAdd(x: Int)(y: Int) : Future[Int]= Future {
    x + y
  }

  def curriedMultiply(x: Int)(y: Int) : Future[Int] = Future {
    x * y
  }

}
```

I am getting the below compiler error when getting the value

```
Type mismatch, expected: Awaitable[NotInferedT], actual: Int => Future[Int]
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted this: `val x: Int => Int = curriedMultiply(10)(i) andThen { m => Await.result(curriedAdd(10)(m),Duration.Inf) }`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez This is giving a type mismatch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to compose two functions of type `Int => Future[Int]` (type of both functions after applying first argument), then execute the result function on parameter `2` and wait for result. If my assumption is correct then you can't just use `andThen` because you need to model behaviour where domain (input type) and co-domain (output type) of the functions are not the same.

You can go native scala way by doing like this:

```
def combine(x:Int) = curriedMultiply(10)(x) flatMap (curriedAdd(10))
//or: val combine  = curriedMultiply(10)(_:Int) flatMap curriedAdd(10)

val y = Await.result(combine(2),Duration.Inf)

println(y)
```

or use `cats` library because functions of type `Int => Future[Int]` are `Kleisli` functions, so you can compose them:

```
import cats.data.Kleisli
import cats.implicits._

val kfk = Kleisli(curriedAdd(10)) compose Kleisli(curriedMultiply(10))

val x = Await.result(kfk(2),Duration.Inf)

println(x)
```

> could you please explain how the flatmap works here.

Following happens when you apply `combine` function to argument `2` :

1. `curriedMultiply(10)(2)` returns `Future[Int]` containing `10 * 2` value (`Future(10 * 2)`)
2. `curriedAdd(10)` returns `Int => Future[Int]` function which is `y:Int => Future(10 + y)`
3. Now you have `Future(10 * 2).flatMap(y => Future(10 + y))`
4. `flatMap` returns `Future` produced by its arguments's function. where 
   `y` is a value produced by left-side `Future` calculating value `20`

Comment: could you please explain how the flatmap works here.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Learned new concept today.